# Do we use do/does with which?

Tags: questions

The question is, "Which boy sings folk songs very well ?" or "Which guy does sing folk songs very well ?". Which one should we use ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You'd only normally phrase your question as *Which guy does sing folk songs very well?* with stress on the word ***does***, as a follow-up to an assertion like *[some guy] **doesn't** sing folk songs very well*. In which case it might be a genuine enquiry, or it might be a rhetorical question (implying that everyone knows ***no** guys sing folk songs very well*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct one:

> Which boy sing**s** folk songs very well?

The other one is totally wrong. The auxiliary verb *do*/*does* is only used with interrogative words like what, how, how often, when and where. So, if your sentence starts with one of those, then you must use do or does. For example:

> How does he sing?
>   He sings well.
>
> Where does he sing?
>   He sings at Marriott Marquis in New York.
>
> What songs does he enjoy singing the most?
>   His favorite songs are mostly of the American folk music genre.

Answer (score 0):

The correct question would be:

> Which boy sing**s** folk songs very well?

The question is in present tense, so we add an "s" to the end for subject-verb agreement. Source: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/sv_agr.htm

Comment: But other ones (what, how, how often) take do/does and make it simple present. What's the difference ?

Comment: Do and does are verbs (linking verbs), and can be used in verb phrases, but action verbs with "s" on the end also work in most cases. Examples: "He walks." "She runs." "What dances?" "CrazyMatt thinks."